# Find Indexof in MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I find the `indexof` in `GetWindowsText`?

I just want to get extensions from `box->fileExt->GetWindowsText(save);`
For example my input is `.exe .txt .bmp`

So I want to get them separately. For example something like that:

```
.exe
.txt
.bmp
```

Currently my code is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files; i++)
        {
            box->testBox1.AddString(save);
            fileExtensions.Add(save)`enter code here`;
            CString check;
            box->fileExt.GetWindowText(check);
            CString store = check;
            check.Find(' ') == save;
            break;
            continue;
            if (fileExtensions[fileCounter] == store)
            {
                box->textBox2.AddString(fileExtensions[fileCounter]);
                fileCounter++;
            }


        }//end for
```

It does not work.

Comment: .exe .txt .bmp is separate lines.

Comment: Edited a little bit. Please feel free to replace my generic "It does not work" with what exact does not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split string based on separator character(s). You can use `Tokenize` method of `CString` to do that:

```
CString sExtensions(_T(".exe .txt .bmp"));
CString sExt;
int nCurPos = 0;
CString sSeparators(_T(" ;"));
CStringArray Extensions;

sExt = sExtensions.Tokenize(sSeparators, nCurPos);
while (!sExt.IsEmpty())
{
   Extensions.Add(sExt);
   sExt = sExtensions.Tokenize(sSeparators, nCurPos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew with the help of your code. My code is work perfect.